# Other than "Final Point"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing a blog post, and I'm almost done. There's left a summary to write in my last abstract and I want to name it. So I came up with "Final Point", but that doesn't sound. Can you suggest anything? Thnx

Comment: It would help if you would edit your question to tell us exactly what you're trying to express and why *Final Point* is inadequate. Otherwise, all we can do is guess, which will only get you an answer by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an *afterword*, or simply *final word*?

Comment: Wrapping up, At the end of the day, To conclude ..., In conclusion, Final thoughts, From the Fountainhead [:-) - genuinely the name of an opinion column by a computer industry shooting-star long ago), It's a wrap, Finally

Comment: thnx alot both :)